# How to share session between multiple application in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, subdomain, codeigniter-3

i have 2 client web and 2 admin dashboad web, which is developed on codeigniter. i want to share session between them. is it possible ?

this is the path structure:

```
main-path: --application 1
               --client web 
               --admin web
           --application 2
               --clinet web
           --application 3
               --admin web
           --system
```

this is the logics:

```
client web -> client web = only need one session,
admin web  -> admin web = only need one session
```

FYI: i am using subdomain in this porject url.

please enlight me. best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy when your applications remain on the same domain.

You can do it via `session_set_cookie_params` function, or via `/application/config/config.php` file, under the Cookie section.

Edit the following lines.

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'yourdomain_';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.yourdomain.com'; //make it visible to all subdomains
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Please note that if used, `$config['encryption_key']`  and `$config['sess_cookie_name']` should have the same values on both applications.